# preg_match_all: Include non-ASCII characters

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a *preg_match_all* to search for words in a paragraph. It does not find Cyrillic characters, etc. How can I alter this to do all types of characters (English, Cyrillic, accented characters, etc.):

```
preg_match_all( '/\b' . $testWord .'\b/i', $content, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );
```

I have tried just adding *u* to the end of the regex and that seems like a solution but I am asking here to see if that is the best practice or if there is a better way to do the regex I am showing.

```
preg_match_all( '/\b' . $testWord .'\b/iu', $content, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );
```

Thank you

Comment: You are approaching this the wrong way I believe...I would say replace your testWord with `\p{L}+` which matches any kind of letter from any language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately even with the `u` modifier the word boundary shorthand `\b` can act up (i.e. not match where you'd expect it to.) You'll want to replace them with negative lookarounds to check for `\pL` (any letter) or `\pM` (any combining accent mark.)

Like so:

```
preg_match_all(
    '/(?<![\pL\pM])' . $testWord .'(?![\pL\pM])/iu',
    $content,
    $matches,
    PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE
);
```

Comment: Thanks -- that worked well for me. I tested with Russian, French Hebrew and Chinese words.